# Nvidia driver not working with all Ubuntu releases on PC

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia

Using Ubuntu 18.04/Ubuntu 21.04:

Computer cannot boot successfully when nvidia drivers are installed, but works fine with nouveau.
PC was working previously, and last week both OSes which are on separate disks just stopped booting. Now any Ubuntu OS I install works fine until the nvidia driver is installed. The OS will start booting, stop right after fschk.

Since then I've tried:
Ubuntu 18.04
Ubuntu 21.04
Kernel Versions: 5.3.x 5.4.x 5.8.x 5.11.x
New mobo bios update
Installing Nvidia drivers from website, old versions, etc.
Using an 3060 ti.

PC:
5600x
Gigabyte B550 Aorus Elite AX V2
RTX 3070 FE
DDR4 3600MHZ CL16

Comment: What version of Nvidia? How are you installing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any driver newer than 460.73.01 doesn't work for me.
All earlier 460 drivers do work. Seems like others are facing the same issue.